# Deploying MVC application to Azure with Language Resource Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am deploying an MVC 5 website to a Windows Azure website. Running locally, the site works as expected. When I publish to the site, I get the following error.

```
  Compilation Error

    Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

    Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Update with some interesting behaviour. I have a dev and staging site on Azure. Publishing to the dev site works fine. Publishing to the staging site does not. The settings are identical.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some searching around on other sites, one solution that worked for others was to go to the Resource files' properties and set the Build Action to 'Content".

This did not work for me, but setting it to 'Embedded Resource' did.

Comment: I commented above, but this only is working on my dev site. Not on the staging. AFAIK, the settings are identical.